# Getting 'Typerror: Text object is not callable in tkinter ' in the following code

Tags: python, tkinter

I am creating a text editor and am getting:

> Typerror: Text object is not callable .

this code is to show a scrollbar where user can scroll in the text editor

```py
import tkinter as tk

class PyText:
    def __init__(self, master):
        master.title("Untitled Text")
        master.geometry("1200x700")      
        self.textarea = tk.Text(master)
        self.scroll = tk.Scrollbar(master, command =self.textarea.yview)
        self.textarea(yscrollcommand =self.scroll.set)      
        self.textarea.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
        self.scroll.pack(side =tk.RIGHT)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    master = tk.Tk()    
    pt = PyText(master)

    master.mainloop()
```

This is the error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "editor.py", line 15, in <module>
    pt = PyText(master)
  File "editor.py", line 9, in __init__
    self.textarea(yscrollcommand = self.scroll.set)
TypeError: 'Text' object is not callable
```

It should show the scrollbar but it is showing error .

Comment: Did you mean `self.textarea.yscrollcommand =self.scroll.set`?

Comment: Should be `self.textarea.config(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

> Set the Text widget's yscrollcommand option to the Scrollbar's set
>   method.
>
> ```
> txt['yscrollcommand'] = scrollb.set
> ```

instead of :

```
self.textarea(yscrollcommand = self.scroll.set)
```

use:

```
self.textarea['yscrollcommand'] = self.scroll.set
```

or:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

class PyText():
    def __init__(self, master):
        master.title("Untitled Text")
        master.geometry("1200x700")
        self.textarea = tk.Text(master)
        self.textarea.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew", padx=2, pady=2)
        self.scroll = tk.Scrollbar(master, command =self.textarea.yview)
        self.scroll.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='nsew')
        self.textarea['yscrollcommand'] = self.scroll.set

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    pt = PyText(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

otuput:

[image]